# Can you say 'you' after 'cut off'?

Tags: word-usage

If you cut or rip something off somebody (I know it must seem a little strange to ask a question about this context, but I am writing a rap song and want to be sure about this phrase) and you want to say: '*I rip your head off*', could you also say the following?

> 'I rip your head off you'

Would it still make sense or just sound weird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example would work, but it's certainly sounds odd.

To my ear at least, your sentence makes sense, but implies that you are *holding* your head rather than, for want of a better word, *wearing* it.

I would opt for

> I rip your head off

Rather than the strange

> I rip your head off *you*

As suggested by Scott in the comments, *I rip you head off your body* would work, but still sounds less idiomatic than my preferred version.

Comment: Or, "I rip your head off ***your body***."

Comment: Yes that would work